# Sharing work/industry related information with colleagues and peers?

Tags: communication, productivity, technology

In the old days, I used to get a memo with some newsclippings in my in-tray that we would all read and then we would initial it and pass it around. I find that emails disappear into Outlook. Begging people to read my blog isn't fun. RSS feeds have a lot of marketing junk. And just plain keeping up with the amount of content takes up a lot of time. With today's tech, what's the best way to find meaningful info about my industry, put together a quick take on things and share it with my larger team?

Comment: `I used to get a memo with some newsclippings in my in-tray that we would all read and then we would initial it and pass it around.` -- What's wrong with doing this now? Instead of clippings you send emails. Nuff said. right? Or can you clarify your exact question or problem.

Comment: This is how we do it now, yes. But, I don't know about where you work, but I get literally over a hundred emails daily so I'd really like to get these "clippings" another way. And also, even when I've saved emails about something interesting, after a month, it's hard to remember exactly what email or folder contained the info and Outlook's search function isn't all that great. Does that make sense?

Comment: What about a weekly newsletter or biweekly. Someone collects interesting stuff over a week or two and then puts it together. The incentive to save the newsletter may be higher than just one clipping. BTW saving emails is still a lot easier than a paper clipping. Are you really going to lose an email easier than a pieces of paper? I wish I could CTRL+SHIFT+F the pile of paper on my desk!!

Answer (score 1):

> With today's tech, what's the best way to find meaningful info about
>   my industry, put together a quick take on things and share it with my
>   larger team?

There are many, many ways to find information about your industry. Websites, blogs, Google Alerts, conferences, friends, etc, etc - all can contain information that you might find useful.

As far as sharing it with your larger team, there are also many ways. A quick email with a link to the source, an intranet page, a corporate wiki, a department newsletter - all could be a good vehicle.

You haven't indicated what your role with your "larger team" is. If you are a Manger or Lead, sending something around that you feel is useful is very reasonable.

If you are a peer, you may want to get a sense of how your peers feel about what you are sending/posting, and dial it back a bit if they start to feel "nagged".

I created a folder of industry-related information in my department's corporate intranet site (I'm the Director of the department). Before doing so, I asked my team if they would find such information useful, and if they would contribute as well. Some have contributed, some just read.

I also have a personal blog, that a few of the folks on my team read. I don't send them links to that blog, as I don't want to be pushy, although I have paraphrased items and sent them on occasion.

Create a good feedback loop for yourself, then try something. Be prepared to revise it if it isn't giving your audience what they (and you) feel they need. That way, over time, it will become more and more useful.

Comment: I get what you're saying but as I said in my OP, there is SOOO MUCH info out there that I could spend all day googling and not do any real work. But I feel like if I don't do it, I'm missing something which could not only increase my knowledge but also stand out among my workmates. Anyway, it just feels inefficient. Setting Google Alerts is a start.

Comment: @ScottGraph to add to this maybe you could schedule a biweekly meeting brief, like say 30min-1hr for open discussion with the team? Then each time bring the latest 3-6 interesting things there to talk about. Maybe it address your "email hole" problem and lead to team development??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 21st century name for this is "curated content."

I have done this the old-fashioned way you describe -- pass around the weekly copy of EE Times with yellow sticky notes.

I've also done it with an internal wiki. That's a good way for a team to do things because anybody can contribute.   But it takes real work to get an internal wiki to the tipping point, where the whole team uses it.

Blogs work. But people don't read stuff like that. If you put the following line in the third paragraph of a blog post I suspect you will be safe:  "If you read this, come to me, tell me this password -- unicorn -- and I will give you x dollars."

Some colleagues are doing it with a web site called paper.li . That seems to have some power.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about! How do they like it? How come you haven't (I'm assuming) started a paper.li newspaper yourself?